# How to pass an id from a razor view to a controller's action method in ASP .Net MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

So, here what bothers me with my first demo MVC Project . In my main view MyAction.cshtml , when you click on the Student UserName hyperlinks a partial view containing Student Details get rendered in the StudentDetails `<div>`.

Here is my main view :

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication4.ViewModels.StudentViewModel>  
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyAction";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_myTemplateLayoutPage.cshtml";
    }

<script>
    function RegisterClickHanders() {

        var url = '@Url.Action("DisplayClickedView","Private")'; 
        $('.editDetails').click(function () {
            var btnvalue = $('.editDetails').attr("value");
            var srchvalue = $(this).closest("tr").children().first().text();
            $('#Add_Update_Details').load(url, { searchText: btnvalue, searchValue: srchvalue });
        });
    }
</script>

<div id="content">
    <div id="mainpage">

    <h2>Registration Details</h2>
        <ul>
        @foreach(var item in Model) 
        {
            <li>
                @Ajax.ActionLink(item.UserName,
                "GetUserDetails", 
                new { id = item.Student.StudentId },
                    new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        UpdateTargetId = "StudentDetails",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                        HttpMethod = "GET",
                        OnComplete="RegisterClickHanders"
                    }
                )
            </li>
        }
        </ul>
        <div id ="StudentDetails"></div>
        <div id ="Add_Update_Details"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="sidebarbottom"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the partial view that gets rendered :

```
@model MvcApplication4.ViewModels.StudentViewModel

<h2>Student Details</h2>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            User Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Department
        </th>
        <th colspan="2">
            Actions
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.StudentFullName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor( x => x.DepartmentName)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" class="editDetails" value="Edit Details" name="Command" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" class="addDetails" value="Add Details" name="Command" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now the details that I show from the StudentViewModel contain StudentId too. Here is the StudentViewModel Class :

```
//View Model
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "StudentName")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Student Name cannot be left blank")]
    public String StudentFullName
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("{0} {1}", Student.FirstName, Student.LastName);
        }
    }

    public String UserName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public String Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password",ErrorMessage="Passwords do not match")]
    [Display(Name="Confirm Password")]
    public String C_Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Department Name")]
    public String DepartmentName { get; set; }

}
```

But I only show StudentFullName , UserName and DepartmentName in the view.

```
     [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult GetUserDetails(int? id)
    {
        StudentContext context = new StudentContext();

        var result = context.Students.Where(s => s.StudentId == id)
            .Include(s => s.Department)
            .Select(s => new StudentViewModel
                {
                    Student = s,
                    UserName = s.UserName,
                    DepartmentName = s.Department.DepartmentName
                }).First();

        return PartialView("_StudentDetails",result);

    }
```

But when click on the Edit Details button I want a view to be  rendered for that record. What I am trying to do is :

```
   var url = '@Url.Action("DisplayClickedView","Private")'; 
        $('.editDetails').click(function () {
            var btnvalue = $('.editDetails').attr("value");
            var srchvalue = $(this).closest("tr").children().first().text();
            $('#Add_Update_Details').load(url, { searchText: btnvalue, searchValue: srchvalue });
        });
```

**But this would get the StudentFullName in the srchvalue and based on that the partial view would be rendered. But I want it to be rendered based on the StudentId itself which is not there in the view.**

[image]

How can I pass the StudentId to the action DisplayClickedView so that the update or edit happens based on the id itself ?

Comment: Could you please show that ? I am not able to understand how would I get the StudentId itself when it is not there in the table .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I want to have some value inside a html property and access it in a javascript, i like to use the [`data-*`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) attribute.

So, you can do something like this:

`<input type="submit" class="editDetails" value="Edit Details" name="Command" data-student-id="@Model.StudentId"/>`

And get it in your javascript:

```
var studentId = $('.editDetails').data("student-id");
```

This way you don't have to add a new "hidden" column inside your table neither change the default properties of your button.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `StudentID` to your view model.  Then you can add an `href` to your buttons via razor which includes the student id:

```
@model MvcApplication4.ViewModels.StudentViewModel

<h2>Student Details</h2>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            User Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Department
        </th>
        <th colspan="2">
            Actions
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.StudentFullName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor( x => x.DepartmentName)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="@Url.Content(~/Controller/Action")/@(x => x.StudentID)" type="submit">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="@Url.Content(~/Controller/Action")/@(x => x.StudentID)" type="submit">Add Details</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Where controller and action are replaced with your controller and action.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.Id" />
```